# DateTime comparison not working PHP

Tags: php, string, datetime, time

timing comparison not working out if passed dynamically

```
$date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));                                  
    $myTime =$date->format('H:i');
    $myDay =$date->format('l');
if(($s<=$myTime) && ($e>=$myTime||$e=="00:00")) 
  {$open =1;}
```

Following works if hard coded

```
if(("11:30"<="05:39")&&("23:00">="05:39"||"23:00"=="00:00"))
      {$open =1;}
```

where m i going wrong

Comment: $open will never be 1 in these examples

Comment: its always "1"  if first one is used not the hard coded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you are using strings to compare time. Convert to timesstamp using strtotime (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or mktime(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or use DateTime class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). When comparing strings they are not compared as time, but as character sequences.

Comment: can u provide working example

Comment: You will have lots of examples on the php manual pages, just scroll down.

Answer (score 2):

```
// your first date  
$dateA = '2008-03-01 13:34'; 
// your second date 
$dateB = '2007-04-14 15:23'; 
if(strtotime($dateA) > strtotime($dateB)){ 
   // something here
}
```

Comment: m just using time format ( H:i)

Comment: convert the time into seconds then compare the two times use strtotime.

Comment: check this http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/9cbec4dcfbe6c8e018cc

Comment: no need to convert to seconds strtotime will do.

Comment: strttotime will convert the time into seconds.I just told to use that function to convert ur time.